# How can I send a message with discord.py without tts reading it out?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py, text-to-speech

I am playing around with a `discord` bot using `python` and `discord.py`. I have `TTS` enabled on `discord` and even when I use the tag `tts=False` whenever I get the bot to send a message to channel it reads out the message using `tts`. I am at a loss on how to disable this as the documentation simply says to use `tts=Fals`e, which is what I am doing. So in the below example when `.ping` is typed the `tts` reads out `"Bot says My ping is 10ms`" and sends the same message to the channel, and I want it to just send the message to the channel and not read it out.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is running")

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"My ping is {round(client.latency * 1000)} ms ",tts=False)

client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 2):

not sure if you want this:

```
@client.command(name="ping", help="Shows latency")
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("My ping is {} ms ".format(round(client.latency * 1000)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your discord settings, you might have TTS Notifications enabled.

Settings > Notifications > Text-To-Speech Notifications > Select "Never"

Comment: It's enabled but I want tts to be enabled for some messages and disabled for others, so I need tts=false to work instead of disabling it in settings.

Comment: Try disabling the setting I mentioned above, and enabling "Allow playback and usage of /tts command" in "Text & Images". 
This way you won't get tts messages constantly, but you will still hear them whenever `tts=True`

Comment: Thank you very much this solved my issue perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

lol just remove this command:

```
#your command :
await ctx.send(f"My ping is {round(client.latency * 1000)} ms ",tts=False)
#fix :
await ctx.send(f"My ping is {round(client.latency * 1000)} ms ")
```

just remove (,tts=False)

this should fix it